# System error 5 occurred. Access is denied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to set time sync to a local server:
`net time \\myserver /set`.
But I get the error System error 5 has occurred, Access is denied.
I am logged in as Administrator, and have opened cmd as Administrator.

The server is a VM, and the client (which is failing) is a physical machine.
Both computers are running Windows Server 2012R2.
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command instead `w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"myserver" /syncfromflags:manual /update`

Also you should review this article about the time service tools
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

> Caution
>
> You should not use the Net time command to configure or set time when
> the Windows Time service is running.

Answer (score 1):

Since you run with full privileges, there may be a remote access problem, as in missing permission to access the remote computer. Before trying to access the remote computer, you should make sure that you have all the required permissions. If any of those are missing, errors will appear like System error 5. You need to get have all the required permissions from/to the remote computer.

Also, try using w32tm if possible.